# VSCode + Xdebug. Step-by-step debugging exits the recursive stack

Tags: php, recursion, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am using **VSCode + PHP + Xdebug**. Wrote a recursive function, trying to debug it. But when the debugger reaches the end of the stack "**return true**", it does not go back up the stack, it just exits. I thought the recursion was probably bad. I tried it with the simplest example, but still the same thing.

For example:

```php
function pow1($x, $n)
{
    if ($n == 1) {
        return $x;
    } else {
        return $x * pow1($x, $n - 1);
    }
}

$result = pow1(2, 3);

echo $result;
```

Debugger reaches **return $x;** and exits the stack with the correct result.

```
pow1 (d:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:6)
pow1 (d:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:8)
pow1 (d:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:8)
{main} (d:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:12)
```

And jump here:

```
{main} (d:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:14)
```

I climbed all the Xdebug settings, tried different options, none of them helped. Rewrote the function to **JavaScript** and debug in the browser.

Comment: Where your breakpoints are? I'm using PhpStorm and after reaching `return $x;` line (after it gets executed) the control is back to `echo $result;` where I have also had a breakpoint. Here is screenshot:https://postimg.cc/v4nLGTyf You have to understand that PHP may generate bytecode differently to JavaScript and debugger experience may be different to other Languages as well as well. Here, in your code, you have "return" statements only. AFAIK Xdebug does not stop at `}` before leaving the function.

Comment: Hello! As I said, I checked everything, including breakpoints, which I put wherever possible.

Comment: Well .. my screenshot shows where my breakpoints are (lines #4 & #13) .. and it stops on them. After stepping over `return $x;` the debugger stops on `echo $result;` line (where the 2nd breakpoint is). That is correct behaviour: all your statements in that function are just returns. This is using PhpStorm 2020.2.4 / 2020.3, PHP 7.4.13 x64 NTS on Windows 10, Xdebug 3.0.1

Comment: I used different programming languages and, accordingly, IDE. Everywhere the behavior is the same, this is the first time I have encountered it. Perhaps I poked something in the settings of the php itself. Therefore, it would be interesting to know the opinion of developers using VSCode.
By the way, developed from GitHub are sent here.